# How to create/destroy a node instance from a Python script

Tags: rosnode, talker

I'd like to have a script that will create/destroy a publisher node. I'm experiencing problems with that, being unable to correctly destroy the node instance. I'm running ROS2 Humble under Windows

I isolated this in a very minimal example, trying to create/destroy a simple existing `demo_nodes_py`/`talker` node. The test verifies that "ros2 topic list" sees the `/chatter` topic created by `talker` after node is created and verifies it's gone after node is destroyed.

```
import sys
import os
import unittest
import time
import rclpy
import subprocess
import signal

class TestCreateDestroyNode(unittest.TestCase):
    """Unit test class."""

    def has_topic(self):
        print(f"Checking global topics...")
    
        worked = False
        try:
            print("Using a 5-sec timeout")
            topics = subprocess.check_output( ["ros2","topic","list"], timeout=5 ).decode()
            worked = True
        except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
            print( "ros2 topic list timed-out" )
            pass
        
        self.assertTrue(worked)
    
        print(f"Found global topics:\n{topics}")
        return (topics.find( "/chatter" ) != -1)

    def test_create_destroy(self):
        
        print( "Verify topic is not present" )
        self.assertTrue( not self.has_topic() )
       
        print("Launching talker")
        process = subprocess.Popen(["ros2","run","demo_nodes_py","talker"], shell=True)
        print("Launched talker")
        
        # Give process a chance to start
        time.sleep(1)
        
        self.assertTrue( self.has_topic() )

        time.sleep(1)
                
        print("Stopping talker")
        process.kill()
        process.wait()
        
        self.assertTrue( not self.has_topic() )
            
if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Run unit test
    unittest.main(__name__)
```

This does not work, after I tried to kill the process, the last `self.assertTrue( not self.has_topic() )` fails and I see /chatter notifications still being displayed in the console.

What's the best/recommended way to create/destroy a node programatically?

Comment: Instead of killing the process, I suggest using ROS 2 Node API. For example, you can call `destroy_node` followed by `shutdown` call. The following references can help: 
[1](https://docs.ros2.org/latest/api/rclpy/api/init_shutdown.html),
[2](https://docs.ros2.org/latest/api/rclpy/api/node.html),
[3](https://answers.ros.org/question/354054),
[4](https://answers.ros.org/question/412104)

Comment: @ravi: But destroy_node needs a Node instance, and I have none as I created the node through a subprocess. I cannot find how to get the Node reference in this case. My Node runs in a different process.

Comment: If thats the case, sending a `SIGINT` signal should be the way as suggested by @Mike973 in the answer section

Answer (score 0):

You should not use python's `process.kill()` like you are, which sends a SIGKILL OS signal to the process. On linux, you should instead send a SIGINT.

Success is also going to depend on the node being written to catch the exception and shutdown cleanly. The talker.py demo code you are using looks correct to me.

Note: a co-worker informs me that on MS-Windows there are severe restrictions on what signals can be sent to another process, and that the python signal name is different from SIGINT (but he didn't remember what it should be.)

Comment: OK, have you tried this? How do you suggest to send SIGINT? Because I tried to replace `process.kill()` by `process.send_signal( signal.SIGINT )` and I get the exception `ValueError("Unsupported signal: {}".format(sig))`. I also tried `process.send_signal( signal.SIGINT )`, this has no effect, the process still runs.

Comment: Updated again. Apparently there are ugly differences between linux and windows platforms in this area.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to "cleanly" exit the created node process using `process.send_signal( signal.CTRL_C_EVENT )` before `process.kill()`. Sinding Ctrl+C makes the node exit cleanly.

Here is the working code:

```
import sys
import os
import unittest
import time
import rclpy
import subprocess
import signal

class TestCreateDestroyNode(unittest.TestCase):
    """Unit test class."""

    def has_topic(self):
        print(f"Checking global topics...")
    
        worked = False
        try:
            print("Using a 5-sec timeout")
            topics = subprocess.check_output( ["ros2","topic","list"], timeout=5 ).decode()
            worked = True
        except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
            print( "ros2 topic list timed-out" )
            pass
        
        self.assertTrue(worked)
    
        print(f"Found global topics:\n{topics}")
        return (topics.find( "/chatter" ) != -1)

    def test_create_destroy(self):
        
        print( "Verify topic is not present" )
        self.assertTrue( not self.has_topic() )
       
        print("Launching talker")
        process = subprocess.Popen(["ros2","run","demo_nodes_py","talker"], shell=True)
        print("Launched talker")
        
        # Give process a chance to start
        time.sleep(1)
        
        self.assertTrue( self.has_topic() )

        time.sleep(1)
                
        print("Stopping talker")
        try:
            process.send_signal( signal.CTRL_C_EVENT )
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Ignoring Ctrl+C")
            pass
        except:
            print("Failed to send Ctrl+C")
            pass

        try:
            process.kill()
        except:
            print("Failed to kill")
            pass

        try:
            process.wait()
        except:
            print("Failed to wait")
            pass
        
        self.assertTrue( not self.has_topic() )
            
if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Run unit test
    unittest.main(__name__)
```

This test passes. However, I keep this question as unanswered, because I believe there must be an easier and nicer way to achieve this.