# ROS2, why killing a child process node also stops parent node?

Tags: python, ros-humble

Based on [this code](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/107749/36667), under Windows using Humble release, I start/stop a child process running a demo_nodes_py's talker:

```
import sys

import rclpy
from rclpy.executors import ExternalShutdownException
from rclpy.node import Node

from std_msgs.msg import String

import subprocess
import signal
import time
import os

class Talker(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('my_talker')
        self.i = 0
        self.pub = self.create_publisher(String, 'my_chatter', 10)
        timer_period = 1.0
        self.tmr = self.create_timer(timer_period, self.timer_callback)

        self.child_process = None

    def timer_callback(self):
        msg = String()
        msg.data = 'Hello World: {0}'.format(self.i)
        self.i += 1
        self.get_logger().info('Publishing: "{0}"'.format(msg.data))
        self.pub.publish(msg)
        
        if (self.i % 5) == 0:
            if self.child_process == None:
                print("Creating child talker")
                self.child_process = subprocess.Popen(["ros2","run","demo_nodes_py","talker"], shell=True)
            else:
                print("Stopping child talker")
                try:
                    self.child_process.send_signal( signal.CTRL_C_EVENT )
                    time.sleep(1)
                except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    print("Ignoring Ctrl+C")
                    pass
                except:
                    print("Failed to send Ctrl+C")
                    pass
        
                try:
                    self.child_process.kill()
                except:
                    print("Failed to kill")
                    pass
        
                try:
                    self.child_process.wait()
                except:
                    print("Failed to wait")
                    pass
                
                self.child_process = None
    
                print("Done stopping child")

def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)

    node = Talker()

    try:
        rclpy.spin(node)
        print("Done spinning")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print(f"Detected Ctrl+C (PID:{os.getpid()})")
        pass
    except ExternalShutdownException:
        print("External shutdown")
        sys.exit(1)
    finally:
        print("IN FINALLY")
        node.destroy_node()
        rclpy.try_shutdown()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This program outputs:

```
[INFO] [1705922851.394614100] [my_talker]: Publishing: "Hello World: 0"
[INFO] [1705922852.268594300] [my_talker]: Publishing: "Hello World: 1"
[INFO] [1705922853.274774700] [my_talker]: Publishing: "Hello World: 2"
[INFO] [1705922854.280540900] [my_talker]: Publishing: "Hello World: 3"
[INFO] [1705922855.266663700] [my_talker]: Publishing: "Hello World: 4"
Creating child talker
[INFO] [1705922856.268923000] [my_talker]: Publishing: "Hello World: 5"
[INFO] [1705922857.278157700] [my_talker]: Publishing: "Hello World: 6"
[INFO] [1705922857.573983300] [talker]: Publishing: "Hello World: 0"
[INFO] [1705922858.275969100] [my_talker]: Publishing: "Hello World: 7"
[INFO] [1705922858.523318600] [talker]: Publishing: "Hello World: 1"
[INFO] [1705922859.272017200] [my_talker]: Publishing: "Hello World: 8"
[INFO] [1705922859.520745600] [talker]: Publishing: "Hello World: 2"
[INFO] [1705922860.270858800] [my_talker]: Publishing: "Hello World: 9"
Stopping child talker
Ignoring Ctrl+C
Done stopping child
Done spinning
IN FINALLY
```

Why are we reaching "IN FINALLY"? Why is the main process `spin` being stopped?